# We know we cant create object of interface but then how do we create object of Statement or PrepareStatement in jdbc?

Tags: java

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,username,password);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
```

Answer (score 3):

The object created is of a class implementing that interface. The actual class depends on the driver.

Both `getConnection()` and `createStatement()` are factory methods. You can write code that uses the interfaces, but the actual classes are what implements the functionality for that particular database.

A (not true) implementation of `DriverManager.getConnection()` would be as follows:

```
public Connection getConnection(String url, String username, String password) {
    if(url.startsWith("jdbc:mysql:") // We have MySQL
       return new MySQLConnection();
    else if(url.startsWith("SomethingElse")
       return new OtherConnection();
}
```

In reality, the actual class is loaded dynamically, so it doesn't need to be in the compile time classpath. The proper class is loaded (or an error is thrown if a suitable one isn't found) and returned. From therefore on, the `MySQLConnection` class will return a `MySQLStatement` and so forth.

You could write code this way:

```
MySQLConnection con = (MySQLConnection)DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

But that would make your code database specific. In some cases this is warranted, if the `MySQLConnection` class allowed for some functionality that isn't in the `Connection` interface, but in most cases you just want to deal with the `java.sql.Connection` interface and not care about which database is actually being used.

Comment: Show a simple example. (and get +1)

Comment: How's that for an example?

Comment: Is it related to annonymous innerclass?

Comment: Not at all. It's related to dynamic class loading.